# Post permalinks not being parsed in Jekyll on GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've created a new site at GitHub Pages, using Jekyll. I'm using a custom permalink format in the following form:

```
permalink: /:title
```

This is because I've moved my blog over from WordPress and want previously existing links to continue working. When I run the server locally with "jekyll serve", it works fine - however, once it's hosted on GitHub Pages, the links don't get parsed correctly, leading to tags like this one:

```
<a class="post-link" href="/:title">Markdown and HTML</a>
```

Further information - I am using a custom domain, with my _config.yml containing:

```
url: http://domain.com
```

And my CNAME containing:

```
domain.com
```

Could anyone shed some light on why this occurs? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use a functionality that was [implemented](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/3031) in Jekyll 2.5.
As [Github pages runs Jekyll 2.4](https://pages.github.com/versions/), it breaks :-(

The only way to do what you want is to set default permalink in you `_config.yml` file.

```
permalink: :title/
```

Comment: Thanks! I've set the permalink manually using permalink: [whatever] for each post, but only for the old imported ones, as I think any new posts should probably use the date format. :)