# List of the working Jekyll permalinks in GitHub Pages

Tags: github, configuration, jekyll, permalinks, github-pages

I'm currently developing a Jekyll-powered site and the line `permalink: /:path/` that's working in my Jekyll local server, is NOT working either through the **Configuration** (_config.yml) or in the **YAML Front Matter** for each page (file.md) in GitHub Pages. They become literally outputted as *example.com/:path/* instead of *example.com/dir-name/* .

I've tried `permalink: "/:path/"` but still not working, [some said that some permalink will not work in the Jekyll version of GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29072370/4883372). Upon researching, GitHub Pages have a Jekyll version of 2.4.0, that can be found in [its "Dependency versions" page](https://pages.github.com/versions/). There's also no mention of this in the [GitHub Pages documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) in the Jekyll website.

Anybody know the exact list of the working [Jekyll permalinks](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) in GitHub Pages, so I can choose what permalinks to use in my project and for the future readers?

Answer (score 2):

In jekyll 2.4 you just can configure permalink for pages just a little.

Reading `page.rb::template` code here's what we have :

No permalink variable -> `/:path/:basename:output_ext`

Permalink var set to `:pretty`

- index.html -> `/:path/` (/folder/other/index.html -> /folder/other/)
- other.html -> `/:path/:basename/` (/folder/toto/other.html -> /folder/toto/other/)
- code.js    -> `/:path/:basename:output_ext` (/folder/code.js -> /folder/code.js)

I believe that jekyll 3 will be the next github pages version coming with all what you see in the [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/).